# CSS3 Slideshow animation Issue

Tags: css, animation, webkit, slideshow

I've been trying to create a CSS3 animations based slider and I am kind of puzzled by the logic behind the animation and keyframes.

here's what I've done: http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/LzGR7

I created a container for the slider and another container inside the slider container which would hold divs or images. In this case I've decided to put in some images for starter.

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide"><span class="image"></span></div>
    <div class="slide"><span class="image"></span></div>
    <div class="slide"><span class="image"></span></div>
    <div class="slide"><span class="image"></span></div>
    <div class="slide"><span class="image"></span></div>
</div>
```

Then using CSS I've absolutely positioned these containers and images.

```
*, body, html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.slider{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.slide{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.slide .image{
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I've then proceeded to add my animation rules to the .slide class

```
.slide
{
     animation: myanimation 48s ease-in-out infinite;
    -webkit-animation: myanimation 48s ease-in-out infinite;
    -o-animation: myanimation 48s ease-in-out infinite;
    -moz-animation: myanimation 48s ease-in-out infinite;
    -ms-animation: myanimation 48s ease-in-out infinite;
}
```

and added animation rules to each of the class separately using the nth-child pseudo class.

I've observed that the images appear in wrong order, so I added z-index separately to these classes

```
.slide:nth-child(1){
animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;    
-moz-animation-delay: 0s;
-o-animation-delay: 0s; 
-ms-animation-delay: 0s;
z-index:1;
}
.slide:nth-child(2){
animation-delay: 8s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 8s;    
-moz-animation-delay: 8s;
-o-animation-delay: 8s; 
-ms-animation-delay: 8s;
    z-index:2;
}

..... and so on...
```

and began adding images to the span

```
.slide:nth-child(1) .image {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/9yvKmZY.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.slide:nth-child(2) .image {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/j8mBdLD.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

..... and so on...
```

finally added keyframe rules

```
@-webkit-keyframes myanimation {
    0%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    25% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

Everything looks fine and dandy.. But the problem starts when the Image starts animating.
I quite haven't grasped the concept of animation properly I guess..

Hence the slideshow goes bonkers animating with a mind of its own. Sometimes it doesn't even show the right order of the images or it skips the image completely.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or where I went wrong?

Here is a full screen example of the slider: http://fiddle.jshell.net/fatgamer85/LzGR7/23/show/light/

Comment: Playing around with the Fiddle, it looks like the z-index values are causing an issue. For instance when once image(3) may be finished a start getting closer to 0 opacity, because image 1 has the highest z-index it is getting shown

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that if that's what causing the issue, if I remove the z-index the transition does not occur. I've changed the delay properties of 5th to 1st element in reverse order to see if it solves any thing, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one thing about slides that makes you loose a lot of time if you don't know it.

If you delay your animations to the future, the first cicle is different from the others. Most of the elements have the properties that come from the static properties, and not from the animation.

To avoid this kind of prpblems, set you animations delay to the past. This way, the first animation cycle is equal to the others.

Also, it is nice to give yourself some help. In this case, I have set numbers to the left of the slide. This way, you can see really what is going on.

Besides, I have fixed a little bit you keyframes, at leats the webkit ones were wrong.

CSS

```
*, body, html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.slider{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.slide{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: myanimation 48s ease-in-out infinite;
    -webkit-animation: myanimation 48s ease-in-out infinite;
    -o-animation: myanimation 48s ease-in-out infinite;
    -moz-animation: myanimation 48s ease-in-out infinite;
    -ms-animation: myanimation 48s ease-in-out infinite;
    font-size: 100px;
    color: red;
}

.slide .image{
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

.slide:nth-child(1){
    animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;    
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
    z-index:5;
}
.slide:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: -40s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -40s;  
    -moz-animation-delay: -40s;
    -o-animation-delay: -40s;   
    -ms-animation-delay: -40s;
    z-index:4;
}
.slide:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: -30s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -30s;  
    -moz-animation-delay: -30s;
    -o-animation-delay: -30s;   
    -ms-animation-delay: -30s;  
    z-index:3;
}
.slide:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: -20s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -20s;  
    -moz-animation-delay: -20s;
    -o-animation-delay: -20s;   
    -ms-animation-delay: -20s;  
    z-index:2;
}
.slide:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: -10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -10s;  
    -moz-animation-delay: -10s;
    -o-animation-delay: -10s;   
    -ms-animation-delay: -10s;
    z-index:1;
}

@keyframes myanimation {
    0%{ opacity: 0; }
    5%{opacity: 1; }
    20%{opacity: 1; }
    25% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myanimation {
    0%{ opacity: 0; }
    5%{opacity: 1; }
    20%{opacity: 1; }
    25% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
@-o-keyframes myanimation {
    0%{ opacity: 1; }
    25% { opacity: 0.75; }
    50%{ opacity: 0.5; }
    75% { opacity: 0.25; }
    100%{ opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes myanimation {
    0%{ opacity: 1; }
    25% { opacity: 0.75; }
    50%{ opacity: 0.5; }
    75% { opacity: 0.25; }
    100%{ opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes myanimation {
    0%{ opacity: 0; }
    5%{opacity: 1; }
    20%{opacity: 1; }
    25% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes myanimation {
    0%{ opacity: 0; }
    5%{opacity: 1; }
    20%{opacity: 1; }
    25% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
.slide:nth-child(1) .image {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/9yvKmZY.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slide:nth-child(2) .image {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/j8mBdLD.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slide:nth-child(3) .image {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/9VdDjQi.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slide:nth-child(4) .image {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/dqCWOgW.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
.slide:nth-child(5) .image {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/0hUMMuT.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

[corrected demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/LzGR7/32/)

Happy coding !

In the above demo, the 5th image appears for a little bit of time at the start of the animation. This can be corrected adjusting the keyframes:

```
@keyframes myanimation {
 0%{opacity: 1; }
    15%{opacity: 1; }
    20%{opacity: 0; }
95% {opacity: 0;}
   100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

If you draw this in a piece of paper, you will see why; but it's difficult to explain

[new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/LzGR7/38/)

About your fiddle with the bar, you make 2 errors. The problem is that you think that the bar are somehow "inside" the frame, and are bound to that "time". This is not true, you are working with a cycle of 40s, and the bar has to work with that animation time (not 9 seconds, and frames in fractions of this 9 seconds).

Your best option is to have only 1 bar, and make it cycling faster (at 10 seconds).

CSS

```
*, body, html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.slider{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
}

.slide{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    animation: bg_anim 50s ease-in-out infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bg_anim 50s ease-in-out infinite;
    -o-animation: bg_anim 50s ease-in-out infinite;
    -moz-animation: bg_anim 50s ease-in-out infinite;
    -ms-animation: bg_anim 50s ease-in-out infinite;
}

.slide .image{
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
}

.slide:nth-child(1){
    animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;    
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
    z-index:5;
}
.slide:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: -40s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -40s;  
    -moz-animation-delay: -40s;
    -o-animation-delay: -40s;   
    -ms-animation-delay: -40s;
    z-index:4;
}
.slide:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: -30s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -30s;  
    -moz-animation-delay: -30s;
    -o-animation-delay: -30s;   
    -ms-animation-delay: -30s;  
    z-index:3;
}
.slide:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: -20s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -20s;  
    -moz-animation-delay: -20s;
    -o-animation-delay: -20s;   
    -ms-animation-delay: -20s;  
    z-index:2;
}
.slide:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: -10s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -10s;  
    -moz-animation-delay: -10s;
    -o-animation-delay: -10s;   
    -ms-animation-delay: -10s;
    z-index:1;
}

.text{
    right: 0px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 28px; 
    float: right;
    z-index:1;
}

.text:nth-child(1){
    z-index:5;  
}

.text:nth-child(2){
    z-index:4;  
}

.text:nth-child(3){
    z-index:3;  
}

.text:nth-child(4){
    z-index:2;  
}

.text:nth-child(5){
    z-index:1;  
}


.bar{
    position: absolute;
    width: 45%;
    height: 400px;
    right: -20px;
    float: right;
    z-index: 99;
    animation: bar_anim 10s infinite ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: bar_anim 10s infinite ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: bar_anim 10s infinite ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: bar_anim 10s infinite ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: bar_anim 10s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation-delay: -1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.5s; 
    -moz-animation-delay: -1.5s;
    -o-animation-delay: -1.5s;  
    -ms-animation-delay: -1.5s;
}

.slide:nth-child(1) > .bar{
    animation-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;    
    -moz-animation-delay: 0s;
    -o-animation-delay: 0s; 
    -ms-animation-delay: 0s;
}

.slide:nth-child(2) > .bar{
    animation-delay: -7.2s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -7.2s; 
    -moz-animation-delay: -7.2s;
    -o-animation-delay: -7.2s;  
    -ms-animation-delay: -7.2s;
    z-index:4;
}

.slide:nth-child(3) > .bar{
    animation-delay: -5.4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -5.4s; 
    -moz-animation-delay: -5.4s;
    -o-animation-delay: -5.4s;  
    -ms-animation-delay: -5.4s;
    z-index:3;
}

.slide:nth-child(4) > .bar{
    animation-delay: -3.6s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -3.6s; 
    -moz-animation-delay: -3.6s;
    -o-animation-delay: -3.6s;  
    -ms-animation-delay: -3.6s;
    z-index:2;
}

.slide:nth-child(5) > .bar{
    animation-delay: -1.8s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: -1.8s; 
    -moz-animation-delay: -1.8s;
    -o-animation-delay: -1.8s;  
    -ms-animation-delay: -1.8s;
    z-index:1;
}

@keyframes bar_anim {
    0%   {  right: -4000px; }
    10%  { right: 0px;  }
    15%  { right: -20px;}
    80%  { right: -20px;}
    95%  { right: 0px;  }
    100% { right: -4000px; }
}
@-o-keyframes bar_anim {
    0%{ right: -4000px; }
    10%{        right: 0px; }
    15%{        right: -20px;   }
    80% {       right: -20px;   }
    95% {       right: 0px; }
    100% {      right: -4000px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes bar_anim {
    0%{         right: -4000px; }
    10%{        right: 0px; }
    15%{        right: -20px;   }
    80% {       right: -20px;   }
    95% {       right: 0px; }
    100% {      right: -4000px; }
}
@-ms-keyframes bar_anim {
    0%{         right: -4000px; }
    10%{        right: 0px; }
    15%{        right: -20px;   }
    80% {       right: -20px;   }
    95% {       right: 0px; }
    100% {      right: -4000px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes bar_anim {
    0%{         right: -4000px; }
    10%{        right: 0px; }
    15%{        right: -20px;   }
    80% {       right: -20px;   }
    95% {       right: 0px; }
    100% {      right: -4000px; }
}

@keyframes bg_anim {
    0%{         opacity: 1; }
    15%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    95% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes bg_anim {
    0%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    15%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    95% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-o-keyframes bg_anim {
    0%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    15%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    95% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes bg_anim {
    0%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    15%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    95% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-ms-keyframes bg_anim {
    0%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    15%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    20%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    95% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, set 1 span for every slide if you need to, but then keep the animation time and delays.

Comment: Hi vals,

is it a standard practice to use negaive values for timing ? sorry I don't know much about this. Also why are the keyframes percentages for webkit different from the rest of keyframes?

Comment: Yes, it is standard practice to achieve that effect. About the percentages, I fixed the webkit ones, and then edited the others; Looks like I forgot to update some.

Comment: so how do I stop the 5th frame from showing first? do I hide it or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Added demo with the corrected code. Difficult to explain how to calculate that !

Comment: could you have a look at this http://fiddle.jshell.net/fatgamer85/t44S9/1/ and tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Your selectors .bar:nth-child(x)  don't match your HTML. All your bar are a second child. You should be using .slider:nth-child(x) > .bar because it's the bar in the  nth slider that you want to target

Comment: aah!, I give up! all this negative numbering melts my brain! The timing of the blue color image (called bar) isnt right.

the first  bar disappears just while animation is happening, second bar should come in, instead its already showing and going out, the third bar  waits till 2 transitions happen to go away.

could you please gave a look and let me know where I went wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/fatgamer85/t44S9/6/

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the blue bar ?

Comment: I am trying to do the slideshow with the images, as you can see.. What the blue bar has is a sentence and a button which would fade in slowly as the blue bar appears on the screen and stays still. then the sentence and button fade out and the bar goes back in, and the background changes. This would continue indefintely.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you have grasped the animation (keyframes) correctly. I think the issue is with the z-index, you should remove it. You missed a tiny single detail about the slide nth-child. You must set the nth-childs opacity to 0. I will leave the understanding to you :)

```
.slide:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 16s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 16s;   
    -moz-animation-delay: 16s;
    -o-animation-delay: 16s;    
    -ms-animation-delay: 16s;   
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: I removed the z-indexes and added opacity to all the nth-child classes.

The animation is still not up to the mark as it fades in real quickly and more ever it doesn't even display one of the slide!